# Unloading and reloading audio causes kivy to crash

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, kivy, kivy-language

I have a music player app made with **kivy and ffpyplayer as its audio provider**. There is a problem that if the user wants to play another audio file, kivy completely crashes without raising any errors, this is the exit code I get with pycharm:

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

And again no errors just a crash and this message from pycharm. I realized it is when I unload the audio then play it that this crash will happen. If I just pause the audio then it won't have a problem but I don't the previous file to just sit there and take up so much memory.

Here is my code:

```
import os
os.environ["KIVY_AUDIO"] = "ffpyplayer"
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from kivy.app import App


class Example(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.song = SoundLoader.load("C:/Users/PC/Downloads/10_poker_face.mp3")
        self.kv = Builder.load_string('''
#:kivy 2.0.0
Button:
    text: "Change Song"
    font_size: 32
    on_release: app.change_song()
''')

    def build(self):
        return self.kv

    def change_song(self):
        if self.song:
            self.song.unload()  # Works fine if I change this line to 'self.song.stop()' but sits in the memory
        self.song = SoundLoader.load("C:/Users/PC/Downloads/ava_max_-_kings_queens.mp3")
        if self.song:
            self.song.play()

    def on_start(self):
        if self.song:
            self.song.play()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Example().run()
```

Comment: I think you should ask the devs directly with this kind of error. https://discord.gg/n3vFBtbt

Comment: @Utopion, asked it there, apparently they are not so eager

Comment: I saw post about audio on the discord and you always have an answer when you ask right. (which is not always the case in SO)

Comment: @Utopion, so my question has a problem?

Comment: I think your question is good but it is complicated, having no error message means it's not really well knwon/handled so few people can help you and they will have difficulty to do so. I think audio is not a priority so it may takes time to find the solution, if you are ready to help and contribute, you have more chance to get help. :) You need to dig into the github and be more and more precise.

Comment: @Utopion, I guess going into github is my last option